# How to know if a C# incorporated video is finished? (COM component)

Tags: c#, video

I have had add in toolbox ( choose item -> COM components -> Windows Media player ) 
In the control proprietes i can choose video's path, but i would know how know if video is finished, at the moment that video finish i need to do some events.
The control have any proprietes like for example a text box , and have not a events..
How i can do??

Answer (score 0):

You should use **PlayStateChange** event of WMP ActiveX.

Look on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
this.VcVideo.PlayStateChange += new  AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(VcVideo_PlayStateChange);
```